# php code showing up on webpage

Tags: php, html

I am new to php. Currently I am following the tutorial on this website:[tutoialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_validation_example.htm). The code is also on that website.

The problem I am facing is with the action tag on line 66. I am getting extra characters on my form page because of it. Also, when I submit the form it goes to "Not Found" page.
[image: form page]
[image: submission page]

I can fix this by leaving action tag blank. However, I would like to know why this error is happening with the default code.

```
    <html>   
   <head>
      <style>
         .error {color: #FF0000;}
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php
         // define variables and set to empty values
         $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
         $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

         if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
               $nameErr = "Name is required";
            }else {
               $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
               $emailErr = "Email is required";
            }else {
               $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

               // check if e-mail address is well-formed
               if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
               }
            }

            if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
               $website = "";
            }
            else {
               $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
               $comment = "";
            }else {
               $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
               $genderErr = "Gender is required";
            }else {
               $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
            }
         }

         function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
         }
      ?>

      <h2>Absolute classes registration</h2>

      <p><span class = "error">* required field.</span></p>

      <form method = "post" action = ">?php 
         echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Name:</td>
               <td><input type = "text" name = "name">
                  <span class = "error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
               </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>E-mail: </td>
               <td><input type = "text" name = "email">
                  <span class = "error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
               </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>Time:</td>
               <td> <input type = "text" name = "website">
                  <span class = "error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
               </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>Classes:</td>
               <td> <textarea name = "comment" rows = "5" cols = "40"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>Gender:</td>
               <td>
                  <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "female">Female
                  <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "male">Male
                  <span class = "error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
               </td>
            </tr>

            <td>
               <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
            </td>

         </table>

      </form>

      <?php
         echo "<h2>Your given values are as:</h2>";
         echo $name;
         echo "<br>";

         echo $email;
         echo "<br>";

         echo $website;
         echo "<br>";

         echo $comment;
         echo "<br>";

         echo $gender;
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `>?` to `<?` in `<form method = "post" action = ">?php 
         echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code 
`<form method = "post" action = ">?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`

would be

```
 <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form should look like this 
`<form method = "post" action = "<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>">`